# Unable to push to github using terminal because it thinks I'm a different user

Tags: git, terminal

I've only used the github desktop client in the past and wanted to learn about using the terminal and git. I was doing a tutorial, and when it came time to push my local repo to github, I get the error:

```
remote: Permission to user/repo denied to other-user
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

It seems that the SSH associated with the desktop client works fine, but the SSH associated with the terminal is under an ex-coworker (other-user). So github thinks that I am my ex-coworker who doesn't have permission to mess with the repo and thus throws the error.

My question is how do I safely identify and delete his old SSH so that I can generate and add a new SSH that's my own?

**Solved: I didn't mention I'm on a mac which has an app that saves passwords called Keychain. I opened up the app and found my ex-coworker's git credentials in there and nuked them. Everything works as expected now**

Comment: That error is _not_ an SSH error. See the URL it contains? You're using HTTPS, not SSH.

Comment: Yeah looks like you have an anonymous (i.e. read-only) clone using HTTP. You either need to clone it again using the git@github.com:user/repo URL or edit the URL for the remote. That will make it use SSH, and allow pushing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The problem was solved by deleting the saved profile in keychain.